# My mouse got lagging with Ubuntu 15.04 on DELL XPS 8500 DESKTOP

Tags: mouse

My mouse got lagging when i made update from Ubuntu 14.04 bits GNOME to Ubuntu 15.04 64 bits. In other distro like "12.04 64 bits, 14.04 bit and UBUNTU 14.04 GNOME bits", I never have had that problem, only on the UBUNTU 15.04 64 bits. Somebody know what happened?

Comment: Whats your video adapter? Are Videos running smooth?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same on my ThinkPad T430. Mouse starts lagging after suspending and wake up laptop. When I extract mouse receiver and plug-in it again mouse stop lagging. This is not mouse and receiver problem because on another computer with Ubuntu 14.04 they works perfectly.